# Which statement will successfully invoke the function?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

```
         create or replace function calc_player_avg
            (v_id IN player_bat_stat.player_id%type)
         return number 
         is
         v_avg number;
         begin
             select hits / at_bats
             into v_avg
             from player_bat_stat
             where player_id = v_id;
             return (v_avg);
         end;
```

Invoking includes "Execute" statement but here the following statement is marked wrong:

```
         Execute calc_player_avg(31);
```

The correct one is:

```
         select calc_palyer_avg(player_id) from player_bat_stat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the first is wrong as the object is a function, so you needed to have a variable to capture the return.

```
SQL> execute calc_player_avg(31);
BEGIN calc_player_avg(31); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'CALC_PLAYER_AVG' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL> var avg number;
SQL> execute :avg := calc_player_avg(31);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL> print avg

       AVG
----------
        .4
```

Comment: Oh yeah ! functions needs return value. How can I forget such an important fact. Thanks :)